# Removing user from Sharepoint User group api call succeds but user not getting deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angular2

The below code is the to remove a user from the SharePoint user group, the API call returns a 200 but the user not getting from removed from the SharePoint user group.

```
removeUserFromUserGroup(email): void {
const listUrl = `/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('Team WhatIf')/users/removeByLoginName`;
let url = this.sharepointService.getappUrl() + listUrl;
url = this.sharepointService.targetUrl(url);

const h = new HttpHeaders({
  Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
});

this.httpClient.post
  (`${this.sharepointService.getappUrl()}/_api/contextinfo`, {}, { headers: h })
  .toPromise().then(
    (res: any) => {
      const dig = res.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
      console.log(dig, 'Digest valuee');

      const body = {
        // __metadata: { type: 'SP.User' }, // table name
        loginName: `i:0#.f|membership|${email}`
        // // 'Title':'test', //values
        // // 'Test':'test'
      };

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Accpet: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'X-RequestDigest': dig
        // 'IF-MATCH': '*',
        // 'X-HTTP-Method': 'DELETE'
      });

      const option = { headers };
      this.httpClient.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), option).subscribe(r => {
        console.log(r, 'success');
        // this.toasterService.success('Evidence Submitted Succesfully', 'Hooray!!', { positionClass: 'toast-top-right' });
      }
      );
    }); }
```

The response I get is 200. Please, someone, help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, you are referencing `removeByLoginName` but you are passing email ID to delete the user. so try the below code,

**Deleting user by Email ID:**

```
'use strict';  
var hostweburl;  
var appweburl;  
// Get the URLs for the app web the host web URL from the query string.  
$(document).ready(function()  
{  
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.  
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));  
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));  
    // Resources are in URLs in the form:  
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource  
    // Load the js file and continue to load the page with information about the folders.  
    // SP.RequestExecutor.js to make cross-domain requests  
    $.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getuser);  
});  
function getuser()   
{  
    var executor;  
    var userEmail = "karthik@jagan.onmicrosoft.com";  
    // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.  
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);  
    executor.executeAsync({  
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups(6)/users/getbyemail('" + userEmail + "')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",  
        method: "POST",  
        headers: {  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert("User Deleted successfully in SharePoint Group");  
        },  
        error: function(err) {  
            alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));  
        }  
    });  
}  
//Utilities  
// Retrieve a query string value.  
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.  
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {  
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");  
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {  
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");  
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];  
    }  
}
```

**Deleting user by Login Name:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var removeUserUrl = "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Employee')/users/removeByLoginName";  
        var metadata = {  
            'loginName': 'i:0#.w|SharePointHOL\\KarthikJagan'  
        };  
        removeUser(removeUserUrl, metadata)  
    });  

    function removeUser(removeUserUrl, metadata) {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + removeUserUrl,  
            type: "POST",  
            headers: {  
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
            },  
            data: JSON.stringify(metadata),  
            success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);  
                console.log("User has been successfully removed from the SharePoint Group.");  
            },  
            error: function(error) {  
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
            }  
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

For more information, kindly have a look at the below links,

1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-and-remove-users-from-security-group-in-sharepoint-2016-using-rest-api/
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1c70bfb1-039d-43cd-94b5-6138893bde8b/rest-api-removedelete-sp-user-from-group?forum=sharepointdevelopment
3. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-delete-users-from-the-group-in-sharepoint-using-rest/

Comment: Thank you Karthik it did the trick